# Remove substring before a specific char (NSString)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring, substring

Basically I am getting a users city throughout Facebook Connect. The result is always in this format:

Sydney, Australia

But since there will be many users, the city and country can vary. Here is the format:
First the city with a comma, then a space and the country.

I only want to however retrieve the country name. Is it possible for me to locate the comma in string, then remove everything behind it. Then I can `replaceOccurancesOfString:" "` to remove the space.

I have seen other questions on this but they are in different languages. I am asking for Objective-C

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one easy way to do it is to use `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator` to make an array out of it, and then pick the second object of the array.

Comment: Yes exactly, I just assigned an array to that then got the second object :)!

Comment: (you can of course also use `- (NSRange)rangeOfString:(NSString *)aString` to get the location of your comma, and then use `- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)aRange` to get the substring. Personally I like the method I put as answer.)

Comment: I suggest `NSLog(@"%@", [@"City, Country" substringToIndex:[@"City, Country" rangeOfString:@","].location]);` .. Up to you